# Change random load to ordered

Tags: javascript, rotator

I have a random URL loading script, but I need to change it to ordered, so each link is visited in order(as it rotates on load), then returns to the first and starts again.
Any help would be appreciated, especially as javascript is like a foreign language to me.

Code:

```
    var ie=document.all&&navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera")==-1
    var dom=document.getElementById&&navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera")==-1

    //Specify IFRAME display attributes
    var iframeprops='width=100% height=100% marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0 vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"'

    //Specify random URLs to display inside iframe
    var randomcontent=new Array()
    randomcontent[0]="slots/001/index.php"
    randomcontent[1]="slots/002/index.php"
    randomcontent[2]="slots/003/index.php"
    randomcontent[3]="slots/004/index.php"

    //No need to edit after here
    if (ie||dom)
    document.write('<iframe id="dynstuff" src="" '+iframeprops+'></iframe>')

    function random_iframe(){
    if (ie||dom){
    var iframeobj=document.getElementById? document.getElementById("dynstuff") :         document.all.dynstuff
    iframeobj.src=randomcontent[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomcontent.length)]
    }
    }

    window.onload=random_iframe

    </script>
```

Comment: You may need to set cookies to loaded them sequentially every time

Comment: no, this code loads the pages in an iframe, so you don't need to persist anything.  but this is pretty atrocious code; where on earth did you get it, and why do you need to do this?

Comment: @Eevee yes, but the `src` attribute was set randomly. Now you need to set cookies to determine which was the last iframe shown and which one is next.

Comment: I can't remember where, I did a lot of searching online, to find something that worked, but couldn't find anything quite right. I have a site that rotates URL's in an iframe, and each one of those is also a rotator, although they are not in an iframe.